# How do I display a histogram with normalized counts?

Tags: graphics, histograms, probability-or-statistics

I have some data corresponding to real number distances: `{200.04053, 200.232123, 156.3242,...}`, and I would like to bin these values and display them as a histogram where the heights of each bar in the histogram are normalized so that the sum of all the bin heights is equal to one.  The objective here is for me to be able to use `FindDistributionParameters` to determine, well, appropriate distribution parameters, and then to overlay the PDF of this suggested distribution on my actual data.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the argument `"Probability"` to the `Histogram` command.  To be precise, if `list` is your list of data, then

```
Histogram[list,Automatic,"Probability"]
```

should do the trick. The `Automatic` argument specifies the bin size.

[image]

Comment: Why does this appear to be dwarfed by the PDF of something like an InverseGaussianDistribution?  Is that simply because of the long RHS tail for my data?

Comment: E.g. ::: Show[Histogram[DATA, Automatic, "Probability"], 
 Plot[PDF[InverseGaussianDistribution[30.11455031212564`, 
    17898.020946792625`], x], {x, 25, 50}, Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotRange -> All]]  (I'm not claiming that this is the right distribution)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "dwarfed"? That said, I'm not a statistician, so even if I understood your question, I probably couldn't provide you with a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Sorry, I fooled myself into thinking that the bins weren't summing to one, but that's not the case.  Thanks for your great answer!